# What is the right way to modify the size of a custom compound view?

Tags: android

Hi I am wondering for this question for a long time. I have a custom vertical progress bar which is based on a `LinearLayout` and has several children like `Textview` and `ImageView`s. I have tried overriding `onMeasure`, `onLayout` and `onDraw`, all of these works and I am a bit confused. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: …and unless you post some code and a specific error/problem, you will be wondering for an even longer time…

Comment: one more way to do this - using `View.setLayoutParams()` method